# A rigorous definition of indexed unions and intersections

Tags: set-theory

When reading material on formal set theory, I have always been bothered by the apparent oversight of informality regarding indexed unions and intersections. For the sake of brevity, I only discuss unions.

Suppose we have

$$
\bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}}S_i := \{ x : \exists i \in \mathcal{I}.x \in S_i \}.
$$

But this is informal still, because we have not explicated what the $S$ symbol is in this case. Should we think of $S$ as a function $S: \mathcal{I} \to C$, $C$ being an arbitrary codomain? Then, we would have

$$
\bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}}S_i := \bigcup \mathrm{Im}(S : \mathcal{I} \to C).
$$

Still, this seems unnatural and wrong, since we have supplied additional information in the definition, namely $C$. It seems more appropriate to use Replacement in the following way:

$$
\bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}}S_i := \bigcup \{ z : \exists i \in \mathcal{I}.\varphi(i,z) \land \forall i \in \mathcal{I}\exists!y.\varphi(i,y)\} = \bigcup R(\varphi,\mathcal{I}).
$$

Replacement is needed to prove that, indeed, $\bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}}S_i$ exists for every formula $\varphi$ with appropriate variable restrictions following the definition of Replacement, and set $\mathcal{I}$.

Am I at least somewhat correct? I'm interested in the most elegant way to handle this mathematical object.

**Addendum.** Per Zhen Lin's suggestion, here is an amended second definition which avoids the worry about the codomain.

$$
\bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}}S_i := \bigcup \{x \in \mathrm{Im}(S) : \mathrm{Dom}(S) = \mathcal{I} \land \text{$S$ is a function} \}.
$$

In the degenerate case where $S$ is an arbitrary set without the structure of a function or without the appropriate domain, the indexed unions is simply $\bigcup \emptyset = \emptyset$.

Comment: @user2661923 My objection was not that the concept of indexed unions and intersections isn't *intuitively clear* (it is, and I understood it prior to posting this question). Rather, it is rigor I am concerned with. I am approaching this from a logician's point of view. Until you write down the formal FOL definition of an object, you *do not* understand it formally.

Comment: If the codomain bothers you then get rid of it. It is traditional in material set theory to not worry about codomains anyway.

Comment: @ZhenLin Hmmm, a very interesting suggestion. I will add an edit with an amended definition.

Comment: I wouldn't say your take is accurate, that the definitions are informal or non-rigorous. We're introducing notation in terms of set builder notation here and the "problem" only arises because you want the definition to metalogically constitute a mapping from sets to sets. We don't have to operate this way. E.g. the common $\bigcap z := \{x : \forall (y\in z). x\in y\}$ is a proper class for $z=\{\}$. This can be "fixed" with different definitions, but we don't have to. Instead, say you write $\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$ for the union of the image IF it's established that $S$ is a set and a function.

Comment: @Nikolaj-K The motivation for the metalogical mapping is that in that case I can use extension by definition.

Comment: So you want a foundational system with a single sort just to formally overhaul it when entering the door? In any case, it looks like [metamath](https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmset.html) (which notably uses a logic calculus with free set parameters everywhere, and, on a different note, a file organization they regret) seems to keep the indexed union at the class level, [here](https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/df-iun.html). Then the image thing is a theorem, [here](https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/funiunfv.html).

Comment: @Nikolaj-K "So you want a foundational system with a single sort just to formally overhaul it when entering the door?" I do not know what you mean by that.

Comment: You argued that you want to make that particular definition by extension, i.e. altering the formal setup of the theory. Say you're doing math in your theory, and when you have proved the existence of some set $f$ that is a function. You could also just in that case introduce abbreviations "$\cup_{i\in I}f_i$", representing the less concise expression involving set builder notation and the image of the function. This would be a placeholder always expanding to a different kind of symbols. That's more mundane than, say, introducing a term $\emptyset$ which is defined by a property _about_ it.

Comment: And after all, you can always find something which is not formalized. For example, when reading some book full of formal derivations, how would you know that not every 7th line ought to be read from right to left. Doing math, there's always informal overhead. Lest you're just writing a compiler, but then you can also wildly program symbol substitution to the extent the programming language allows you. Next thing you're questioning the rigor of the language you write your compiler with. Why start at set theory at all, and not [rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_rewriting_system).

Comment: @Nikolaj-K I am taking Compilers this semester, so I know about rewriting/production rules. Funnily enough, the theory about them does include at least some informal finite sets. The rabbit hole goes on... :)

Answer (score 3):

You will not find any formal definition of $\bigcup_{i \in I} S_i$ when doing formal set theory because it is (usually) not part of formal set theory.
In fact, formal set theory (usually) has no operations whatsoever.
For example, in ZFC, the axiom of union states simply:

> For every set $s$ there exists a set $u$ such that $v \in u$ if and only if there exists $t \in s$ such that $v \in t$.

Or, if you prefer, in symbols:

$$\forall s . \exists u . \forall v . (v \in u \leftrightarrow \exists t . (t \in s \land v \in t))$$

By the axiom of extensionality, the $u$ given by this axiom is unique, so *informally* we can define a unary operation $\bigcup$ on sets by

$$\forall s . \forall v . \left( v \in \bigcup s \leftrightarrow \exists t . (t  \in s \land v \in t ) \right)$$

and if you insist on doing things formally, this is an example of [extension by definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_by_definitions).

Indexed unions are more tricky.
Before we can even formalise $\bigcup_{i \in I} S_i$ we would have to formalise what $S_i$ means – this is the actual hard part!
Commonly, $S_i$ is the result of applying a function $S$ to $i$... but what is a function?
You could identify functions with their graphs, which are sets of ordered pairs... but what is an ordered pair?
I hope you see what I am getting at.
Then there is the additional subtlety of showing that logical formulae that define functions can actually be incarnated as functions in the sense you choose – for this you typically use the axiom of replacement.

(It is worth noting that the axiom of replacement is usually *not* needed when you do already have $S$ incarnated as a function.
Specifically, if you have a set of Kuratowski pairs representing the graph of $S$, then you can use the basic axioms to reduce the graph of $S$ to the image of $S$, and then you can use the usual axiom of union.
Often this happens if you know in advance that each $S_i \subseteq X$ for some known set $X$.
You may want to check your understanding of this by thinking about $V_{\omega + \omega}$, which is a model of Zermelo set theory (i.e. ZFC minus replacement).)

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am aware of extension by definitions. In fact, this was my exact guide in determining what is "formal." If I can define the extra symbols (as we know, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proper only has $\in$) with extensions, this is satisfactory to me.

Comment: I guess what I would suggest to people writing set theory books which are serious about formality is that when you introduce new notation, you *must at least hint* at how these fresh symbols can be justified with extension by definitions.